EF SqlException (0x80131904) When Max Batch Size > 5 in Azure SQL Server
When I have a batch size larger than five in my database context, I get the exception below. If the batch size is 5 or lower, no error happens. I changed the timeout to 300 but it did not solve the issue. In fact, the exception immediately fires, without waiting the timeout.
{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ReceiveAsync(Socket socket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveAsync(Memory`1 buffer, SocketFlags socketFlags, Boolean fromNetworkStream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNINetworkStream.<>n__0(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNINetworkStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SNIStreams.ValueTask.cs:line 72
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[<ReadAsync>d__1](<ReadAsync>d__1& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNINetworkStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SslOverTdsStream.NetCoreApp.cs:line 84
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[<ReadAsync>d__5](<ReadAsync>d__5& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.AsyncReadWriteAdapter.ReadAsync(Stream stream, Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync>d__161`1[[System.Net.Security.AsyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Security.SslStream.<EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync>d__161`1[[System.Net.Security.AsyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]], System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Security.SslStream.<EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync>d__161`1[[System.Net.Security.AsyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]], System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(Int32 result)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, Int32 result)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetResult(Int32 result)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SslOverTdsStream.NetCoreApp.cs:line 173
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.<ReadAsync>d__5, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5]].ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.<ReadAsync>d__5, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5]].MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.<ReadAsync>d__5, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(Int32 result)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, Int32 result)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetResult(Int32 result)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNINetworkStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SNIStreams.ValueTask.cs:line 83
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNINetworkStream.<ReadAsync>d__1, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5]].ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNINetworkStream.<ReadAsync>d__1, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5]].MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNINetworkStream.<ReadAsync>d__1, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.<>c.<.cctor>b__49_0(Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SignalCompletion()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore`1[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetResult(Boolean result)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs _)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompletedInternal()
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationAsyncSuccess(Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionCallback(Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags, SocketError socketError)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.TransferCompletionCallbackCore(Int32 bytesTransferred, Memory`1 socketAddress, SocketFlags receivedFlags, SocketError socketError)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.BufferMemoryReceiveOperation.InvokeCallback(Boolean allowPooling)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.OperationQueue`1[[System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.ReadOperation, System.Net.Sockets, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].ProcessAsyncOperation(ReadOperation op)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.ProcessAsyncReadOperation(ReadOperation op)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.ReadOperation.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.AsyncOperation.Process()
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.HandleEvents(SocketEvents events)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEngine.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNINetworkStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SNIStreams.ValueTask.cs:line 77
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SslOverTdsStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SslOverTdsStream.NetCoreApp.cs:line 91
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync>d__161`1[[System.Net.Security.AsyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Security.SslStream.<EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync>d__161`1[[System.Net.Security.AsyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]], System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ReadAsyncInternal>d__163`1[[System.Net.Security.AsyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Security.SslStream.<ReadAsyncInternal>d__163`1[[System.Net.Security.AsyncReadWriteAdapter, System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]], System.Net.Security, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNISslStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SNIStreams.ValueTask.cs:line 28
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__211_0(Task`1 result) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs:line 2654
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[[Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5],[System.Data.Common.DbDataReader, System.Data.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__281_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ClientConnectionId:606c1b87-0d60-4b3b-bb38-eed46b0d2c71
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d[[System.ValueTuple`2[[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__31`2[[System.ValueTuple`2[[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__31`2[[System.ValueTuple`2[[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__30`2[[System.ValueTuple`2[[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Core.DAL.UnitOfWork.SaveInspection(InspectionRecord inspection, Dictionary`2 failedImages) in D:\EagleEye\Core\DAL\UnitOfWork.cs:line 308}

The related classes are as follows:
public class InspectionRecord
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The PK, auto-incremented
    /// </summary>
    public int InspectionRecordId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The date of the inspection
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime InspectionDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the inspector
    /// </summary>
    public string? Inspector { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The notes from the inspection
    /// </summary>
    public string? Notes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The calculated overall condition rating
    /// </summary>
    public float OverallConditionRating { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The FK to the structure
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int BridgeId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The navigation property to the structure
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Bridge Bridge { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of element records for the inspection
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ElementRecord> ElementRecords { get; set; } = [];
}

public class ElementRecord : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The PK, auto-incremented
    /// </summary>
    public int ElementRecordId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The condition rating of the element.
    /// </summary>
    public byte ConditionRating
    {
        get => conditionRating;
        set
        {
            conditionRating = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ConditionRating));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Notes about the element.
    /// </summary>
    public string? Notes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The FK to the element
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int ElementId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The navigation property to the element
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Element Element { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// The FK to the inspection
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int InspectionRecordId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The navigation property to the inspection
    /// </summary>
    public virtual InspectionRecord InspectionRecord { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// The navigation property for the inspection images of the element.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ElementRecordImage> ElementRecordImages { get; set; } = [];

    [NotMapped]
    byte conditionRating;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

My database context file is as follows:
public partial class EagleEyeDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Server=<server>;Initial Catalog=<db>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<id>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, 
            options => {
                options.EnableRetryOnFailure()
                .MaxBatchSize(5);
                });
#if DEBUG
        optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new EFCommandInterceptor());
        optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
#endif
    }

    public DbSet<Bridge> Bridges { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Element> Elements { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ImageItem> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InspectionRecord> InspectionRecords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ElementRecord> ElementRecords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BridgeImage> BridgeImages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ElementRecordImage> ElementRecordImages { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Inheritance strategies - default to table per hierarchy

        // cascade delete strategies - see documentation for details

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bridge>()
            .HasMany(b => b.BridgeImages)
            .WithOne(i => i.Bridge)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.BridgeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bridge>()
            .HasMany(b => b.Inspections)
            .WithOne(i => i.Bridge)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.BridgeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bridge>()
            .HasMany(b => b.Elements)
            .WithOne(e => e.Bridge)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BridgeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<InspectionRecord>()
            .HasMany(i => i.ElementRecords)
            .WithOne(e => e.InspectionRecord)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.InspectionRecordId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);  // break multiple cascade paths

        modelBuilder.Entity<Element>()
            .HasMany(e => e.ElementRecords)
            .WithOne(r => r.Element)
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.ElementId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // break multiple cascade paths

        modelBuilder.Entity<ElementRecord>()
            .HasMany(r => r.ElementRecordImages)
            .WithOne(i => i.ElementRecord)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.ElementRecordId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}


This is how I try to save it to the database:
        try
        {
            InspectionRepository.Add(inspection);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            result = InspectionSaveResult.Success();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, "Failed to save inspection");
            result = InspectionSaveResult.Failure("Failed to save inspection, see app log for details");
        }

InspectionRepository is a generic repository which calls dbSet.Add(entity);.
Since the error message is extremely cryptic but reveals that the error is in the database, I created an extended event as follows:
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Session3] ON DATABASE 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[sql_text] like '%INSERT%INTO%ElementRecords%')),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_starting(
    ACTION(sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[sql_text] like '%INSERT%INTO%ElementRecords%'))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'https://<user>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/session3.xel')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO

But I don't see any events in the log. I tried to capture even more detailed events with
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Session2] ON DATABASE 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_starting,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed,
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_starting
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'https://<user>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/session2.xel')
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO

but there were no entries related with the EF errors.
I learnt that SQL Server has a limit of 2100 parameters per batch but my batch has nowhere that limit.
Why could this error happen? Is there any other way to track the origin of this message?

maybe related? https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/2103

You are exceeding the connection pool.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

@MartinSmith I think you're right. I will add some notes to that issue as well
